Can a differentiable function have everywhere discontinuous derivative?
For $n \geq 2$, let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable. Is it possible that $\nabla f$ is everywhere discontinuous?
I believe in dimension $1$, $\nabla f$ has to be continuous on a dense set by the Baire category theorem. The same argument shows that the partials $\partial_i f$ are continuous along lines on a dense set. However, this doesn't seem to apply directly to $\nabla f$ itself, which is a map to $\mathbb R^n$.

Does not Baire category argument prove that each partial derivative, being a pointwise limit of continuous functions, is continuous on the complement of a Baire category 1 set?

@FedorPetrov Please see my reply to Willie Wong’s answer.

I do not understand what is the essence of the discussion. Is not a gradient just a vector of partial derivatives, and a point where they all are continuous is a point where the gradient is continuous?

@FedorPetrov Uh, you are right, for some reason I thought that the Baire argument showed only continuity of the partials along lines, but the argument holds for functions on $\mathbb R^n$ too, so the conclusion does follow from that…

A good reference for properties of derivatives is Differentiation of Real Functions by Andrew M. Bruckner. Theorem 2.1 on page 46 says that $S$ is the set of discontinuities of a derivative if and only if $S$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set. (Admittedly this is a theorem about 1-dimensional functions.)

To spell out Fedor's comment:

For each $i$, you have $\partial_i f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left( f(x + n e_i) - f(x) \right)$ is the pointwise limit of continuous functions, and hence is Baire class 1.

Denote by $C_i$ the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\partial_if$ is continuous, then Baire's theorem says that $C_i$ is comeagre.

Since the dimension $n < \infty$, you have that $C := \cap_{i=1}^n C_i$ is also comeagre, and hence dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the Baire Category Theorem.

Finally we use the calculus results: (a) if a point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that for each $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the partial $\partial_i f$ exists on an open neighborhood of $x_0$ and is continuous at $x_0$, then $f$ is strongly differentiable at $x_0$, in the sense of [1]. (b) if a function $f$ is differentiable on an open set and strongly differentiable at $x_0$, then $\nabla f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
Putting things together we conclude that $\nabla f$ is continuous on $C$.


References:
[1] - Strong Derivatives and Inverse Mappings, Nijenhuis.

Thanks for the answer! Concerning step 4, is it not required that the partials exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood of $x_0$? That’s the classical theorem from calculus I remember. Without the continuity in a neighbourhood, it seems like the rate of differentiability of the partials might be different and thus the function is not strongly differentiable.

Oh and I guess the Volterra function is a counterexample to part (b) of 4.

@NateRiver: you are wrong on both counts, I suspect it may be because you are not familiar with the notion of strong differentiability? The definition is as what is given in this MO question. (What you are thinking of is probably the statement "If all partials exist and are continuous on a neighborhood, then the function is continuously differentiable on the neighborhood." This can be derived as a corollary of 4(a). Note that in 4(a) the conclusion does not claim differentiability away from $x_0$.)

For references: 4(b) is given in paragraph 25.23 in Schechter's Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations.  Assuming 4(b), you can state 4(a) as "strong partial differentiability in all directions imply strong differentiability"; and this is Section 3, Theorem 1 of https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319298 // Note that even in standard textbooks (like Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Apostal) you see a statement that is almost exactly 4(a) except that they only prove the (weaker) conclusion that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, certainly continuity on an entire neighborhood is not required.

(What you really need is that the derivative well approximates difference quotients between points that are sufficiently close to $x_0$, but that is precisely strong differentiability.) // Actually, if you don't want to track down Schechter's book, 4(b) is also proven in the Nijenhuis paper I linked to in the previous comment.

Ohh, by strong differentiability you don't just mean the usual notion of total differentiability, but the stronger condition that the difference quotients are uniformly well approximated. Very nice, I will give those references a read, thanks!

Yes, it is unfortunate that there are two possible interpretations of the phrase "strongly differentiable" (one in opposition to "weakly differentiable" in PDEs and distribution theory, and one that is more restrictive than Frechet differentiability). To that: I am just the messenger, so don't shoot.

Interestingly enough, I have thought about this notion of differentiability before, and even called it “strong differentiability” myself. Charmed to see that it’s actually pretty useful…

So, it seems pointwise strong differentiability is equivalent to pointwise continuity of the derivative for everywhere differentiable functions. For functions that are not necessarily everywhere differentiable, strong differentiability seems to be a way to say “the derivative is morally continuous here” if the derivative actually existed elsewhere. This might also be linked to the sharpness of the inverse/implicit function theorems for functions that are not classically differentiable. Fascinating…

Given what it does, tight differentiability seems to be a nice alternative name to me for the concept.

Strong differentiability at a point is what is required for inverse/implicit function theorems. // A nice interpretation: let $\daleth_x^sf(y) = \frac{1}{s} (f(x + sy) - f(x))$ be the "zooming-in" of the function $f$ centered at $x$ by the scale $s$. Frechet differentiability is equivalent to $\lim_{s\to 0} \daleth_x^s f$ converging uniformly on bounded sets. Strong differentiability is equivalent to convergence in the Lipschitz seminorm. This shows how strong differentiability is just a little bit better than Frechet.

Yep that makes sense, it’s close to a plane in Lipschitz norm. Also, very nice notation for the zooming in!

@WillieWong Could you please provide a reference for 4.(a)?

@rfloc: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473821/can-a-differentiable-function-have-everywhere-discontinuous-derivative/473837?noredirect=1#comment1231135_473837 (there's also a link in the answer that Nate added).

@NateRiver You can also check this Q&A on the notion of "strong differentiability" mathoverflow.net/questions/404397
